# Сайт не адаптируется под разные разрешения

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, bootstrap

Я новичок в вёрстке, решил сверстать шаблон на Bootstrap, для тренировки.
Нашел PSD, верстал и подгонял всё на мониторе 1920х1080px.

[image].

Все вроде нормально получилось, как на картинке, однако когда меняешь разрешение блоки начинают наезжать друг на друга:

[image]

По идее Bootstrap должен красиво их сдвигать. Я может подключил что-то не так?
Сайт закинул на хост, для наглядности: [вот он](http://publer.ru/folio2/index.html)
Прошу не судить строго по коду, я только начинаю верстать :)

Вот код HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Макет</title>
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
</head>

<body data-spy="scroll" data-target=".scroll" data-offset="50">
<header>
<div class="col-lg-12 logo">
 <a href="#"> <img src="img/logo.png"></a>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-1 menu_h" align="center">
        <a href="#">HOME</a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-1 menu_a" align="center">
                  <a href="#">  ABOUT</a>
            </div>
    <div class="col-lg-1 menu_s" align="center">
                  <a href="#"> SERVICE</a>
            </div>
    <div class="col-lg-1 menu_o" align="center">
        <div class="dropdown" >
          <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle btn1"     type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
            OUR TEAM
          </button>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
            <li><a href="#">Team 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Team 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Team 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Team 1</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>

            </div>
    <div class="col-lg-1 menu_p" align="center">
                  <a href="#"> PORTFOLIO</a>
            </div>
    <div class="col-lg-1 menu_b" align="center">
                  <a href="#"> BLOG</a>
            </div>
    <div class="col-lg-1 menu_c" align="center">
                  <a href="#"> CONTACT</a>
            </div>
  <div class="col-lg-1 ic1">
     <a href="#"> <img src="img/icon_wh.png"></a>
  </div>
      <div class="col-lg-1 ic2">
          <a href="#"> <img src="img/icon_bell.png"></a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-1 ic3">
          <a href="#">  <img src="img/icon_search.png"></a>
      </div>

  </div>
  </div>
  </header>
  <content>
  <div class="col-lg-7">
      <ul class="col-lg-4 list">
           <li> <a href="#">Illustrating</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Logos</a></li>
          <li> <a href="#">Graphic Design</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Mobile</a></li>
          <li> <a href="#">Web</a></li>
         <div class="col-lg-12 hr">
          <hr>
         </div>
      </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-5 img1">
              <img src="img/img1_container.png">
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-5 img2">
              <img src="img/img2_container.png">
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-2 img3">
              <img src="img/img3_container.png">
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-lg-7 post_head">
          <h5>Recent Blog Posts</h5>
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-6 post_img">
          <img src="img/recent_post.png">
        </div>
          <div class="col-lg-7  post_body">
            <b>Post Title</b>
            <p class="grey_text">Posted by Admin in Blog</p>
            Иванов Иван Иванович  </br>
            что вы можете сказать о себе?  </br>
            я начинал пыхать с 8 лет </br>
            и теперь не могу жить что бы  </br>
            не пыхнуть пару сотен строчек </br>
            ежедненвно, это как наркотик  </br>
            не пыхайте, ЛЮДИ!!!  </br>
              новенький бульбулятор</br>
              новенький бульбулятор</br>

            <a href="#">Продолжить чтение...</a>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-6 href">
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-7 post_img">
              <img src="img/recent_post.png">
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-7  post_body">
              <b>Post Title</b>
                 <p class="grey_text">Posted by Admin in Blog</p>
                 Иванов Иван Иванович  </br>
                 что вы можете сказать о себе?  </br>
                 я начинал пыхать с 8 лет </br>
                 и теперь не могу жить что бы  </br>
                 не пыхнуть пару сотен строчек </br>
                 ежедненвно, это как наркотик  </br>
                 не пыхайте, ЛЮДИ!!!  </br>
              новенький бульбулятор</br>
              новенький бульбулятор</br>

                 <a href="#">Продолжить чтение...</a>
               </div>


    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6 img4">
            <img src="img/img4_container.png">
        </div>
          <div class="col-lg-6 img5">
              <img src="img/img3_container.png">
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-lg-5 img7">
                  <img src="img/img5_container.png">
              </div>
                <div class="col-lg-7 img8">
                    <img src="img/img6_container.png">
                </div>
            </div>
     </div>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-6 ic4">
             <a href="#"> <img src="img/icon_eye.png"></a>
          </div>

          <div class="col-lg-6 ic5">
              <a href="#"> <img src="img/icon_search2.png"></a>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>

  <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
              <div class="col-lg-3 img9">
                  <img src="img/img7_container.png">
              </div>

              <div class="col-lg-3 img10">
                  <img src="img/img8_container.png">
              </div>

              <div class="col-lg-3 img11">
                  <img src="img/img9_container.png">
              </div>

              <div class="col-lg-3 img12">
                  <img src="img/img3_container.png">
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
  </content>
  <footer>
   <div class="col-lg-12 copy_right">
<img src="img/copy_right.png">
</div>
 <div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-1 line">
        <img src="img/line_footer.png">
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-1 logo1">
              <img src="img/logo1_footer.png">
          </div>
    <div class="col-lg-1 logo2">
              <img src="img/logo2_footer.png">
          </div>
    <div class="col-lg-1 logo3">
        <img src="img/logo3_footer.png">
                  </div>
    <div class="col-lg-1 logo4">
        <img src="img/logo4_footer.png">
                  </div>
    <div class="col-lg-1 logo5">
        <img src="img/logo5_footer.png">
                  </div>
    <div class="col-lg-1 logo6">
        <img src="img/logo6_footer.png">
                  </div>
    <div class="col-lg-1 line2">
                <img src="img/line_footer.png">
                          </div>
 </div>
 </div>
  <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-1 col-lg-offset-7 flogo1">
              <img src="img/icon_facebook.png">
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-1 col-lg-offset-8 flogo2">
                            <img src="img/icon_tube.png">
                        </div>
          <div class="col-lg-1 col-lg-offset-9 flogo3">
                            <img src="img/icon_w.png">
                        </div>
          <div class="col-lg-1 col-lg-offset-10 flogo4">
                            <img src="img/icon_twitter.png">
                        </div>
          <div class="col-lg-1 col-lg-offset-11 flogo5">
                            <img src="img/icon_p.png">
                        </div>
          </div>
      </div>
```

Вот CSS:

```
header{
background: url("../img/bg_nav.png");
height: 100px;
}
header a{
color: #9d9d9d;
}
header a:hover {
text-decoration:none;
color: white;
}
header a:focus{
color: aqua;
text-decoration: none;
}
.logo{
top: 5px;
right: 30px;
}
.menu_h{

margin: 20px;
bottom: 68px;
font-size: 15px;
right: 20px;
}

.menu_a{

margin: 20px;
bottom: 68px;
font-size: 15px;
right: 40px;
}


.menu_s{
margin: 20px;
bottom: 67px;
font-size: 15px;
right: 40px;
}

.menu_o{
margin: 20px;
bottom: 107px;
font-size: 15px;
width: 110px;
right: 50px;
}
.btn1{
background: transparent;
border: 0px;
color: #9d9d9d;
height: 100px;
border-radius: 0px;
font-size: 15px;
}
.btn1:hover{
background-color: transparent;
color: white;
}
.btn1:active{
background-color: transparent;
color: white;
}


.menu_p{
margin: 20px;
bottom: 67px;
font-size: 15px;
right: 40px;
}

.menu_b{

margin: 20px;
bottom: 68px;
font-size: 15px;
right: 40px;
 }
.menu_c{
margin: 20px;
bottom: 67px;
font-size: 15px;
right: 40px;
}
.ic1{
bottom: 57px;
left: 335px;
}
.ic2{
bottom: 58px;
left: 320px;
 }
.ic3{
bottom: 96px;
left: 500px;
}
.dropdown-menu {
margin-top: -3px;
border:none;
background-color: #3B3A40;
border-radius: 0px;
right: -23px;
}          /*Выпадающее меню*/
.dropdown-menu li a{
 color: #9d9d9d;
 }

.dropdown-menu li a:hover{
color:aqua;
text-decoration: underline;
background: #3B3A40;
 }
 .btn-default:active:hover,
 .btn-default.active:hover,
 .open > .dropdown-toggle.btn-default:hover,
 .btn-default:active:focus,
 .btn-default.active:focus,
 .open > .dropdown-toggle.btn-default:focus,
 .btn-default:active.focus,
 .btn-default.active.focus,
 .open > .dropdown-toggle.btn-default.focus {
   color: white;
  background-color: #3B3A40;
  border-color: transparent;
  }/*кнопка при нажатии*/
 .list{
  width: 200px;
  bottom: 100px;
  font-size: 15px ;

  }
 .list li{
list-style-type: none;
margin: 10px;
 }
.list li a{
color: #7A7880;
 }
 .list li a:hover{
color: aqua;
 }

 .img1{
bottom: 345px;
right: -11px;
 }

.img2{
bottom: 345px;
right: 74px;
 }

.img3{
bottom: 345px;
left: 155px;
}
.hr{
width: 320px;
top: 30px;
}
.grey_text{
color: darkgrey;
font-size: 11px;
}
.href a{
color: aqua;

}
.href{
top: -540px;
left: 45px;
}
.post_body{
top: -550px;
left: 45px;
font-size: 12px;
}
.post_img{
top: -505px;
}
.post_head{
top: -530px;
}
.scroll {
visibility: visible;
overflow-y: scroll;
width: 500px;
height: 200px;
scrollbar-base-color: #E8E6EC;
}
.img4{
bottom: 1030px;
left: 11px;

}

.img5{
bottom: 1031px;
left: 545px;

}
.img7{
bottom: 1181px;
left: 11px;

}

.img8{
bottom: 1181px;
right: 74px;

}
.ic4{
bottom: 1247px;
left: 70px;
}

.ic5{
bottom: 1247px;
right: 300px;
 }

.img9{
bottom: 1226px;
left: 10px;
 }

.img10{
bottom: 1226px;
left: 121px;
 }

.img11{
bottom: 1226px;
left: 197px;
 }

.img12{
bottom: 1226px;
left: 253px;
 }
footer{
margin-top: -1226px;
background: url("../img/bg_footer.png");
height: 100px;

}

 .copy_right{
bottom: 396px;
left: 35px;
 }

 .line{
bottom: 448px;
right: 5px;
 }
.logo1{
bottom: 437px;
right: 30px;
}

.logo2{
bottom: 435px;
left: 60px;
}

.logo3{
bottom: 437px;
left: 150px;
}

.logo4{
bottom: 432px;
left: 215px;
}

.logo5{
bottom: 437px;
left: 317px;
}

.logo6{
bottom: 437px;
left: 400px;
}
.line2{
bottom: 448px;
left: 433px;

 }
 .flogo1{
bottom: 495px;
left: 495px;
 }
 .flogo2{
bottom: 530px;
left: 460px;

 }
.flogo3{
bottom: 570px;
left: 438px;

}
.flogo4{
bottom: 612px;
left: 412px;
}
.flogo5{
bottom: 655px;
left: 376px;

 }
```

Comment: дык верстать то надо не только для разрешения `lg`, но и для `md`, `sm`, `xs`. Для начала вам надо бы почитать про верстку на **bootstrap** http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

Comment: 0_o пройди по таториалам, слишком много писать что не так

Comment: Главная Ваша проблема в том, что размеры блоков, элементов меню и т.д. указаны в пикселях. Т.е. фиксировано. А если размер зафиксирован, то bootstrap его не трогает. Для адаптивной верстки лучше использовать сетку boostrap и/или все размеры указывать в процентах. И лучше начинать с размеров `xs`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В CSS:
1. Нужно указать блоки в %  width:50%; width:40%; width:10%;
2. float: left;  - обтекание блока друг за другом слева
3. clear: both; запретить блоку обтекание

4. Кроме этого определять стили для устройств можно и в самом листе стилей с типом медиа: all добавляя в его самый низ указания для каждого отдельного устройства:

   ```
   @media (max-width: 1920px) and (min-width: 1600px) { 
    .list{
         width: 10%;
         float: left; //указываем обтекание для блока
          }
       }

       @media (max-width: 1600px) and (min-width: 1024px) {
    .list{
         width: 10%;
         clear: both; //запрещаем обтекание для блока
   }
   ```

   }
5. Для картинок в блоке указываются параметры width: %; height: auto;